# Gekko returning a clearly non-optimal solution for a simple quadratic problem?

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

Given the program:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()  

tlX = m.Var()
tlY = m.Var()

m.Equation(m.sqrt(tlX*tlX + tlY*tlY)  <= 31 )

m.Maximize(tlX * tlY)

m.solve() 

print("solution: ", tlX.value, tlY.value )
```

Returns:

```
EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
 The final value of the objective function is   0.000000000000000E+000
[0.0] [0.0]
```

Which is clearly not optimal. As `tlX=1, tlY=1` is closer to optimal. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The others that responded are correct that any non-zero initial guess will solve the problem. Even setting a small non-zero value for one of the variables resolves the issue.

```py
tlX = m.Var(value=1e-5)
```

The problem is that the local optimizers find that the initial guess of `[0,0]` satisfies the [Karush-Kuhn Tucker conditions](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/KuhnTucker). Because they are local optimizers, they don't check that the [Hessian (matrix of partial 2nd derivatives)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893456/hessian-matrix-in-optimization) is positive definite for a minimum or negative definite for a maximum.

[image: KKT conditions]

A couple things to consider for global solutions are listed on [this page](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/GlobalOptimization). Here is an example with your problem.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp
from hyperopt import STATUS_OK, STATUS_FAIL

# Define the search space for the hyperparameters
space = {'tlX': hp.quniform('tlX', 0, 1, 0.3),
         'tlY': hp.quniform('tlY', 0, 1, 0.3)}

def objective(params):
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    x = m.Array(m.Var,2,lb=0)
    tlX,tlY = x
    tlX.value = params['tlX']
    tlY.value = params['tlY']
    m.Equation(m.sqrt(tlX*tlX + tlY*tlY)  <= 31 )
    m.Maximize(tlX * tlY)
    m.solve(disp=False,debug=False)
    obj = m.options.objfcnval
    if m.options.APPSTATUS==1:
        s=STATUS_OK
    else:
        s=STATUS_FAIL
    m.cleanup()
    return {'loss':-obj, 'status': s, 'x':x}

best = fmin(objective, space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=10)
sol = objective(best)
print(f"Solution Status: {sol['status']}")
print(f"Objective: {sol['loss']:.2f}")
print(f"Solution: {sol['x']}")
```

Here is the solution:

```
Solution Status: ok
Objective: 480.50
Solution: [[21.920310221] [21.920310221]]
```

Comment: @ John Hedengren: well, simply using solver with hessian, we can find Global Min, VS. using only jacobian that results in finding Local Min -- I finally got understanding this simple way to transform solver from Local to Global opt. tool - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a starting point away from (0,0), which has the unfortunate condition of not having any particularly good search direction

```
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()  


tlX = m.Var(value=1e-5)
tlY = m.Var()

m.Equation(m.sqrt(tlX*tlX + tlY*tlY)  <= 31 )


m.Maximize(tlX * tlY)

m.solve() 


print("solution: ", tlX.value, tlY.value )
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a guess value for the variables tlX and tlY. x = 0, y = 0 is a minimum and the solver gets stuck at the minimum.

```py
tlX = m.Var(value = 0.5)
tlY = m.Var(value = 0.5)
```

It outputs the answer: x=21.920310224, y= 21.920310224

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution by including bounds on the variables

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()  


tlX = m.Var(lb=0,ub=31)
tlY = m.Var(lb=0,ub=31)

m.Equation(m.sqrt(tlX*tlX + tlY*tlY)  <= 31 )


m.Maximize(tlX * tlY)

m.solve() 


print("solution: ", tlX.value, tlY.value )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t1X = m.Var(1)
```

just give an initial guess.

Answer (score 1):

GEKKO is unable to move from the initial guess variable of 0. In this case set an arbitrary none-zero value this is within the bounds of your problem. Example code for a guess value of 5 for each variable is below.

````py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()  


tlX = m.Var(value=5)
tlY = m.Var(value=5)

m.Equation(m.sqrt(tlX*tlX + tlY*tlY)  <= 31 )


m.Maximize(tlX * tlY)

m.solve(disp=False) 


print("solution: ", tlX.value, tlY.value ) ```
````

Comment: I guess this makes sense, in this simple model where it's easy to do. But in a more complex model, how do I know if the optimizer is giving a suboptimal answer?